# Reciprocal sums

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, theta-functions

How can I prove the following?
1)$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2k+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\theta_{2}^{2}(0,\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}),$$
2)$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{k}^{2}}=\frac{5}{24}(\theta_{2}^{4}(0,\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2})-\theta_{4}^{4}(0,\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2})+1),$$

Are there good resources in this case?

Comment: $$ F_n = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\sinh(n\log \varphi)$$

Comment: hence the given series are related with $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\sinh^2(\alpha n)}$

Comment: and this kind of series is related with Jacobi theta functions.

Comment: Yeah, Jack and I know what Jacobi theta functions are. But for the benefit of those here who are not as knowledgeable as Jack and I, you could elaborate on what the thetas in your equations stand for.